# Audio not working on fresh Ubuntu 14.10 install

Tags: sound, 14.10

I just installed Ubuntu 14.10 on this machine but cannot get audio to work at all. Sound config does not show any output device, even though everything works ok on windows.

Here goes the output of alsainfo

```
!!################################
!!ALSA Information Script v 0.4.64
!!################################

!!Script ran on: Sun Nov  9 12:58:36 UTC 2014


!!Linux Distribution
!!------------------

Ubuntu 14.10 \n \l DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.10" NAME="Ubuntu" ID=ubuntu ID_LIKE=debian PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.10" HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/" SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/" BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"


!!DMI Information
!!---------------

Manufacturer:       
Product Name:       
Product Version:    
Firmware Version:  6.00 PG


!!Kernel Information
!!------------------

Kernel release:    3.16.0-24-generic
Operating System:  GNU/Linux
Architecture:      x86_64
Processor:         x86_64
SMP Enabled:       Yes


!!ALSA Version
!!------------

Driver version:     k3.16.0-24-generic
Library version:    1.0.28
Utilities version:  1.0.28


!!Loaded ALSA modules
!!-------------------

snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_intel


!!Sound Servers on this system
!!----------------------------

Pulseaudio:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pulseaudio)
      Running - Yes


!!Soundcards recognised by ALSA
!!-----------------------------

 0 [SB             ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI SB
                      HDA ATI SB at 0xfe024000 irq 43
 1 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI HDMI
                      HDA ATI HDMI at 0xfdffc000 irq 45


!!PCI Soundcards installed in the system
!!--------------------------------------

00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV670/680 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 3690/3800 Series]


!!Advanced information - PCI Vendor/Device/Subsystem ID's
!!-------------------------------------------------------

00:14.2 0403: 1002:4383
    Subsystem: 174b:437b
--
01:00.1 0403: 1002:aa18
    Subsystem: 1787:aa18


!!Modprobe options (Sound related)
!!--------------------------------

snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_usb_caiaq: index=-2
snd_usb_ua101: index=-2
snd_usb_us122l: index=-2
snd_usb_usx2y: index=-2
snd_cmipci: mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2


!!Loaded sound module options
!!---------------------------

!!Module: snd_hda_intel
    align_buffer_size : -1
    bdl_pos_adj : 32,32,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    beep_mode : N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N
    enable : Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y
    enable_msi : -1
    id : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    index : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    jackpoll_ms : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    model : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    patch : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    position_fix : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    power_save : 0
    power_save_controller : Y
    probe_mask : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    probe_only : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    single_cmd : N
    snoop : Y

!!Module: snd_hda_intel
    align_buffer_size : -1
    bdl_pos_adj : 32,32,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    beep_mode : N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N
    enable : Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y
    enable_msi : -1
    id : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    index : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    jackpoll_ms : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    model : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    patch : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
    position_fix : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    power_save : 0
    power_save_controller : Y
    probe_mask : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
    probe_only : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    single_cmd : N
    snoop : Y


!!HDA-Intel Codec information
!!---------------------------
--startcollapse--

Codec: Realtek ALC880
Address: 3
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 0)
Vendor Id: 0x10ec0880
Subsystem Id: 0x08800000
Revision Id: 0x100800
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
Default Amp-In caps: N/A
Default Amp-Out caps: N/A
State of AFG node 0x01:
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
GPIO: io=2, o=0, i=0, unsolicited=1, wake=0
  IO[0]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
  IO[1]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
Node 0x02 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x411: Stereo
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x03 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x411: Stereo
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x04 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x411: Stereo
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x05 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x411: Stereo
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x06 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x211: Stereo Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0x1e]: 16 20 24 32
    formats [0x1]: PCM
Node 0x07 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x10051b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x23, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0x6]: 16 20
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 7
     0x18* 0x19 0x1a 0x1b 0x1c 0x14 0x15
Node 0x08 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x10051b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x23, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0x6]: 16 20
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 7
     0x18 0x19 0x1a* 0x1b 0x1c 0x14 0x15
Node 0x09 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x10051b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x23, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0x6]: 16 20
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 10
     0x18 0x19 0x1a 0x1b 0x1c* 0x0b 0x14 0x15 0x16 0x17
Node 0x0a [Audio Input] wcaps 0x100391: Stereo Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0x1e]: 16 20 24 32
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Connection: 1
     0x1f
Node 0x0b [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Beep Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=5, ofs=0
  Control: name="Beep Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=5, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x23, nsteps=0x41, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0xa3 0xa3] [0xa3 0xa3] [0xa3 0xa3] [0xa3 0xa3] [0xa3 0xa3] [0xa4 0xa4] [0xa3 0xa3] [0xa3 0xa3]
  Connection: 8
     0x18 0x19 0x1a 0x1b 0x1c 0x1d 0x14 0x15
Node 0x0c [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00] [0x80 0x80]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x40, nsteps=0x40, stepsize=0x03, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x40 0x40]
  Connection: 2
     0x02 0x0b
Node 0x0d [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00] [0x80 0x80]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x40, nsteps=0x40, stepsize=0x03, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x40 0x40]
  Connection: 2
     0x03 0x0b
Node 0x0e [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00] [0x80 0x80]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x40, nsteps=0x40, stepsize=0x03, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x40 0x40]
  Connection: 2
     0x04 0x0b
Node 0x0f [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00] [0x80 0x80]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x40, nsteps=0x40, stepsize=0x03, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x40 0x40]
  Connection: 2
     0x05 0x0b
Node 0x10 [Audio Selector] wcaps 0x300101: Stereo
  Connection: 4
     0x0c* 0x0d 0x0e 0x0f
Node 0x11 [Audio Selector] wcaps 0x300101: Stereo
  Connection: 4
     0x0c* 0x0d 0x0e 0x0f
Node 0x12 [Audio Selector] wcaps 0x300101: Stereo
  Connection: 4
     0x0c* 0x0d 0x0e 0x0f
Node 0x13 [Audio Selector] wcaps 0x300101: Stereo
  Connection: 4
     0x0c* 0x0d 0x0e 0x0f
Node 0x14 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40018d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x0000003f: IN OUT HP Detect Trigger ImpSense
  Pin Default 0x00000000: [Jack] Line Out at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x0, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Connection: 1
     0x0c
Node 0x15 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40018d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x0000003f: IN OUT HP Detect Trigger ImpSense
  Pin Default 0x00000000: [Jack] Line Out at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x0, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Connection: 1
     0x0d
Node 0x16 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40018d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x0000003f: IN OUT HP Detect Trigger ImpSense
  Pin Default 0x00000000: [Jack] Line Out at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x0, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Connection: 1
     0x0e
Node 0x17 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40018d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x0000003f: IN OUT HP Detect Trigger ImpSense
  Pin Default 0x00000000: [Jack] Line Out at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x0, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Connection: 1
     0x0f
Node 0x18 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40018d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x0000133f: IN OUT HP Detect Trigger ImpSense
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 80
  Pin Default 0x00000000: [Jack] Line Out at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x0, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x21: IN VREF_50
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Connection: 1
     0x10
Node 0x19 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40018d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x0000133f: IN OUT HP Detect Trigger ImpSense
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 80
  Pin Default 0x00000000: [Jack] Line Out at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x0, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN VREF_HIZ
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Connection: 1
     0x11
Node 0x1a [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40018d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x0000133f: IN OUT HP Detect Trigger ImpSense
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 80
  Pin Default 0x00000000: [Jack] Line Out at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x0, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN VREF_HIZ
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Connection: 1
     0x12
Node 0x1b [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40018d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x0000133f: IN OUT HP Detect Trigger ImpSense
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 80
  Pin Default 0x00000000: [Jack] Line Out at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x0, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN VREF_HIZ
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Connection: 1
     0x13
Node 0x1c [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400001: Stereo
  Pincap 0x00000020: IN
  Pin Default 0x00000000: [Jack] Line Out at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x0, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
Node 0x1d [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400000: Mono
  Pincap 0x00000020: IN
  Pin Default 0x00000000: [Jack] Line Out at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x0, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
Node 0x1e [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400300: Mono Digital
  Control: name="Line Out Phantom Jack", index=0, device=0
  Pincap 0x00000010: OUT
  Pin Default 0x00000000: [Jack] Line Out at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x0, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Connection: 1
     0x06
Node 0x1f [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400200: Mono Digital
  Pincap 0x00000020: IN
  Pin Default 0x00000000: [Jack] Line Out at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x0, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
Node 0x20 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00040: Mono
  Processing caps: benign=0, ncoeff=10
Node 0x21 [Volume Knob Widget] wcaps 0x600080: Mono
  Volume-Knob: delta=0, steps=64, direct=0, val=63
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Connection: 0
Codec: ATI R6xx HDMI
Address: 0
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 0)
Vendor Id: 0x1002aa01
Subsystem Id: 0x00aa0100
Revision Id: 0x100000
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x40]: 48000
    bits [0x2]: 16
    formats [0x1]: PCM
Default Amp-In caps: N/A
Default Amp-Out caps: N/A
State of AFG node 0x01:
  Power states:  D0 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
GPIO: io=0, o=0, i=0, unsolicited=0, wake=0
Node 0x02 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x201: Stereo Digital
  Converter: stream=1, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
Node 0x03 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400381: Stereo Digital
  Control: name="HDMI/DP,pcm=3 Jack", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Con Mask", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Pro Mask", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Default", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="ELD", index=0, device=3
  Pincap 0x00000094: OUT Detect HDMI
  Pin Default 0x18560010: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=01, enabled=1
  Connection: 1
     0x02
--endcollapse--


!!ALSA Device nodes
!!-----------------

crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  2 Nov  9 10:54 /dev/snd/controlC0
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  4 Nov  9 10:54 /dev/snd/controlC1
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  3 Nov  9 10:54 /dev/snd/hwC0D3
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  6 Nov  9 10:54 /dev/snd/hwC1D0
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  5 Nov  9 10:56 /dev/snd/pcmC1D3p
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  1 Nov  9 10:54 /dev/snd/seq
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116, 33 Nov  9 10:54 /dev/snd/timer

/dev/snd/by-path:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  80 Nov  9 10:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 200 Nov  9 10:54 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  12 Nov  9 10:54 pci-0000:00:14.2 -> ../controlC0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  12 Nov  9 10:54 pci-0000:01:00.1 -> ../controlC1


!!Aplay/Arecord output
!!--------------------

APLAY

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

ARECORD

**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****

!!Amixer output
!!-------------

!!-------Mixer controls for card 0 [SB]

Card hw:0 'SB'/'HDA ATI SB at 0xfe024000 irq 43'
  Mixer name    : 'Realtek ALC880'
  Components    : 'HDA:10ec0880,08800000,00100800'
  Controls      : 3
  Simple ctrls  : 1
Simple mixer control 'Beep',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 65
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 36 [55%] [1.00dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 36 [55%] [1.00dB] [off]

!!-------Mixer controls for card 1 [HDMI]

Card hw:1 'HDMI'/'HDA ATI HDMI at 0xfdffc000 irq 45'
  Mixer name    : 'ATI R6xx HDMI'
  Components    : 'HDA:1002aa01,00aa0100,00100000'
  Controls      : 7
  Simple ctrls  : 1
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]


!!Alsactl output
!!--------------

--startcollapse--
state.SB {
    control.1 {
        iface CARD
        name 'Line Out Phantom Jack'
        value true
        comment {
            access read
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.2 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Beep Playback Volume'
        value.0 36
        value.1 36
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type INTEGER
            count 2
            range '0 - 65'
            dbmin -3500
            dbmax 3000
            dbvalue.0 100
            dbvalue.1 100
        }
    }
    control.3 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Beep Playback Switch'
        value.0 false
        value.1 false
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type BOOLEAN
            count 2
        }
    }
}
state.HDMI {
    control.1 {
        iface CARD
        name 'HDMI/DP,pcm=3 Jack'
        value false
        comment {
            access read
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.2 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Con Mask'
        value '0fff000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access read
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.3 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Pro Mask'
        value '0f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access read
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.4 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Default'
        value '0400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.5 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Switch'
        value true
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.6 {
        iface PCM
        device 3
        name ELD
        value ''
        comment {
            access 'read volatile'
            type BYTES
            count 0
        }
    }
    control.7 {
        iface PCM
        device 3
        name 'Playback Channel Map'
        value.0 0
        value.1 0
        value.2 0
        value.3 0
        value.4 0
        value.5 0
        value.6 0
        value.7 0
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type INTEGER
            count 8
            range '0 - 36'
        }
    }
}
--endcollapse--


!!All Loaded Modules
!!------------------

Module
nls_iso8859_1
bnep
rfcomm
bluetooth
6lowpan_iphc
snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_controller
radeon
snd_hda_codec
snd_hwdep
snd_pcm
hid_generic
snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event
usbhid
snd_rawmidi
snd_seq
hid
snd_seq_device
snd_timer
kvm_amd
ttm
kvm
snd
drm_kms_helper
drm
edac_core
i2c_algo_bit
edac_mce_amd
shpchp
serio_raw
k8temp
soundcore
sp5100_tco
i2c_piix4
parport_pc
ppdev
lp
mac_hid
parport
pata_acpi
uas
usb_storage
psmouse
8139too
8139cp
floppy
r8169
mii
ahci
pata_atiixp
libahci


!!Sysfs Files
!!-----------

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D3/init_pin_configs:
0x14 0x00000000
0x15 0x00000000
0x16 0x00000000
0x17 0x00000000
0x18 0x00000000
0x19 0x00000000
0x1a 0x00000000
0x1b 0x00000000
0x1c 0x00000000
0x1d 0x00000000
0x1e 0x00000000
0x1f 0x00000000

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D3/driver_pin_configs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D3/user_pin_configs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D3/init_verbs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC0D3/hints:

/sys/class/sound/hwC1D0/init_pin_configs:
0x03 0x18560010

/sys/class/sound/hwC1D0/driver_pin_configs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC1D0/user_pin_configs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC1D0/init_verbs:

/sys/class/sound/hwC1D0/hints:


!!ALSA/HDA dmesg
!!--------------

[   14.408890] [drm] Loading RV670 Microcode
[   14.606574] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:14.2: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
[   14.898346] [drm] Internal thermal controller with fan control
--
[   14.915506] [drm] radeon: irq initialized.
[   14.916528] sound hdaudioC0D3: autoconfig: line_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:line
[   14.916533] sound hdaudioC0D3:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   14.916536] sound hdaudioC0D3:    hp_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   14.916538] sound hdaudioC0D3:    mono: mono_out=0x1e
[   14.916540] sound hdaudioC0D3:    inputs:
[   14.946584] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 1 usecs
--
[   15.024042] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.39.0 20080528 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
[   15.024178] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle VGA-switcheroo audio client
[   15.025881] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[   15.068319] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input6
[   15.418461] init: Error while reading from descriptor: Broken pipe
```

Thanks

Comment: Hello. This sounds more like a bug report than a question. You should consider filing it, so that the problem can be resolved. Please open the terminal and type `ubuntu-bug alsa` and then follow the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this command to solve the problem

```
sudo alsa force-reload.
```